# Should I edit the answered question?

Tags: discussion, edits

When I surf for my problems I have found a few questions which were asked long ago and had answers, but that had some formatting errors.
Does it make any sense to edit questions which already had an accepted answer and were up voted by a lot of people?

Comment: [Q.E.D.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/294885/revisions)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can suggest an edit to the question to improve formatting and fix grammatical errors.  It may be accepted if the community approves it.

Comment: To clarify:  until you [earn the ability to edit questions/answers freely](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), your edits will be reviewed by *the community*, not specifically a moderator.

Comment: @Makoto, you should *edit this answer* ;)